# v-if inside v-for echoes in vue js

Tags: vue.js

soy nuevo en vue.js, necesito mostrar en una lista el nombre del usuario y el nombre de los países que ha visitado y que si tienen más de un país visitado están separados por una coma "," como en el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: user list]

Esto funciona muy bien con javascript, aquí están los datos y el código de ejemplo:
[image: code]

Lo que necesito es pasar ese proceso del "for" en Vue.js, ya que cuando pongo el segundo v-for me pone el país en otra línea...
[image: example 1]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan orientarme, de antemano muchas gracias.
Saludos!

Comment: Sabes que desde el html en vue puedes invocar funciones de JS verdad? No tienes más que hacer una función que te devuelva lo que quieres, sea uno u más, en un único string y llamarla desde tu html... no tiene sentido intentar hacer estructuras complejas para manipular datos en el html, la manipulación de datos se hace en JS, luego se invoca desde el html.

Comment: De todas maneras, el código es texto, ponlo como tal. Y en vez de poner trozos inconexos, es recomendable poner *TODO* el código relacionado. Sobre todo si te vas a saltar las convenciones y poner de nombre `users.IdCountries` a algo que asumo son las id de país de un determinado usuario... ergo `users` debería ser `user`. Llamarle a las cosas de manera que sirva para determinar su contenido es una muy buena práctica, sobre todo cuando no eres el único que va a leer el código...

Comment: Hola @Benito-B tu comentario me iluminó mucho, hice lo que me recomendaste y pude solucionarlo así que te agradezco mucho tu aporte.